# React Native FlatList Renders Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, react-native

As I see from many posts that there is a huge problem about FlatList rendering multiple times and causes some problem. Its really annoying and so far I couldnt find any solution for this, and I guess many people have the same situation.

Here is the code, so when I alert instead of seeing one value, I see different values which contains undefined..undefined..real value..undefined . I can also describe it like when I put only 1 element (like  {item.message} ) it renders double and makes some spaces between.. like always some strange rendering, so when I add press event on something, I dont get the proper value to alert in press event..

How to solve this flatlist rendering problem??

```
render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <FlatList
                data={this.state.messages}
                renderItem={({item}) =>

                    <View key={item.id}>

                        <Text> {item.sender} </Text>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert(item.id)} >
                            <Text>{item.message} {item.id}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>

                    }
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Comment: no one knows how to solve it? :(

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand the question. Could you post a screenshot of the errors you're seeing?

Comment: I dont see any errors, I explained. I need to see 1 exact value when FlatList renders but , it renders multiple times so I see some undefined values for example.. So I cant handle the press event correctly because of it.. there is many posts about this flatlist rendering problem.

Comment: All I’m gonna day is, a GIF (live demo of the problem) speaks a thousands words.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13597

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14772

Comment: Try including a `keyExtractor` with the item id set as the key. Also, extract your `renderItem` function to a class member, otherwise you're creating a new function every time `render` gets called, which causes React to re-render.

Comment: OK I will include keyExtractor but what you mean about class member?

Comment: Could you resolve this?, i have the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times

Comment: Hi berke and guille, please check my answer for resolve this issue 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669093/3462686

Answer (score 0):

Strange but I solved the problem, and maybe many people have similar problems about flatlist rendering. So problem was caused by backend.

I was creating array in backend before sending to react-native, and there I was doing like this:

```
 $new = new Collection();

 $new[] = array('message' => $message->message);
 $new[] = array('id' => $message->id);
 $new[] = array('sender' => 'Sender: System');

return $new;
```

and after I get the array to react-native I was trying to render in flatlist. I noticed that it renders as many as I added new array(), so I fixed the problem by doing:

```
$new[] = array('message' => $message->message, 'key' => strval($message->id), 'sender' => 'Sender: System');
```

Hope it can help some other people who was similar codes and problem!..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seems that (in my case) 
renderItem would render all the items & depending on how many elements are in the array of data passed to `data={this.state.messages}` the whole list will re-render again.