# FlatList renderItem is being called multiple times

Tags: react-native

**What am I doing ?**

Trying to render a FlatList based on some items stored in `state.data`. A button is present which upon press appends a new item in `state.data`.

**What is the problem ?**

Upon pressing the button, I'm expecting that the renderItem to be called only `state.data.length` number of times whereas it's being called `2*state.data.length` number of times. Also, this 2x behaviour is not always consistent and changes as `state.data.length` increases.

Ex: when `state.data.length=3`, then on initial render, number of times renderItem is called exactly 3 times which is same as the number of items in `state.data` and  upon pressing button which appends a new item to `state.data` and now `state.data.length=4` and renderItem is called 8 times i.e. `2*state.data.length` times.

But, when `state.data.length=11`, then on initial render, renderItem is called exactly 21 times and upon pressing button which appends a new item to `state.data` and now `state.data.length=12` and renderItem is called 23 times times which deviates from `2*state.data.length` behaviour.

[image]

**What am I expecting ?**

renderItem to be called only `state.data.length` number of times on initial and subsequent renderings.

**What I've tried ?**

1. Created a new project from scratch to test this behaviour with no luck.
2. Made component inside renderItem PureComponent. Still the same behaviour as mentioned.
3. Made a CodeSandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-nn73t with react-native-web with the same behaviour as before. Please refer this sandbox for the code.
4. Using props such as maxToRenderPerBatch, initialNumsToRender etc but to no avail either. Though using them with relatively large `state.data` does bring down the number of times renderItem is called but it's still not that great decrease.
5. Referred similar questions but couldn't get much clarity

   - [FlatList renderItem is called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365912/flatlist-renderitem-is-called-multiple-times)>
   - [FlatList onEndReached being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53408470/flatlist-onendreached-being-called-multiple-times)

The real issue I'm facing is when I'm trying to render chat messages (fetching through API call and setting it inside the state) inside a FlatList. Right now there are about ~200 messages for which the renderItem is being called in a range of 800-1200 times which is taking a hit on the performance.

Is this behaviour which is deviating from my expectation expected ? 
If yes, then what's the logic behind this. If no, then what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 8):

I went through your code and tried understanding your concern.

*(renderItem ~ FlatList's prop )*
Note :- **when using flatlist your item of list should be pure component or should implement shouldComponentUpdate or else they will render a lot more time than expected**

So the below points are keeping in mind that your flatlist item are implemented as stated.

1. As per you concern of performance , there wont be any issue though the renderItem is called so many times . When you check how many times you item is actually rendered (by console.log() in your items render) that behaviour is as expected.
   so your ***items are not actually getting rendered*** it is only the renderItem in flatList that is called so many times.

try pressing (*Add Item Immutably* *text*) in the project link shared you will understand better.
[Check This project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-forked-d6k0e).

2. So now the question which remains is why renderItem is called unexpected number of times and how to understand what is happening under the hood ?

Well even i am unaware of how things are implemented but as per what i read in docs i will just share few content that may help.

*"In order to constrain memory and enable smooth scrolling, content is rendered asynchronously offscreen. This means it's possible to scroll faster than the fill rate ands momentarily see blank content. This is a tradeoff that can be adjusted to suit the needs of each application, and we are working on improving it behind the scenes."*

and this is default value of few props which helps in controlling the tradeoff

maxToRenderPerBatch: 10,

onEndReachedThreshold: 2, // multiples of length

scrollEventThrottle: 50,

updateCellsBatchingPeriod: 50,

windowSize: 21, // multiples of length

for understanding more clearly , we need to understand how VirtualizedList is implemented. I will surely update this answer after digging more.

Comment: the code sample really helped me out to fix my issue thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use React.memo for solve this issue

```
<FlatList
renderItem={({item, index}) => <DisplayRenderMemo item={item} index={index} onPress = { async() =>  { } }/>  } 
/>

const DisplayRenderMemo = React.memo(({ item, index, onPress }) => 
 {   
 const count = React.useRef(0);
  return ( 
    <TouchableOpacity 
                    key={index}   
                    onPress={onPress}>
                   <Text>{item.label} {(count.current++)} counts</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
     )
 }, (prevProps, nextProps) => { 
console.log(nextProps, prevProps);
  return nextProps.item.data_id === prevProps.item.data_id 
})
```

First check without using the React.memo like

```
const DisplayRenderMemo = ({ item, index, onPress }) => 
     {   
     const count = React.useRef(0);
      return ( 
        <TouchableOpacity 
                        key={index}   
                        onPress={onPress}>
                       <Text>{item.label} {(count.current++)} counts</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
         )
     }
```

Now it display like 0, 1, 2, 3 counts

Then use the React.memo like above mentioned code

Hurray!!! Now it display only the 0 counts. So we got the solution. It's not re-rendered.

Note: Please make sure which field is unique in `{item}` data. Because we can't use the index as unique. So just pass any unique key with your `{item}` data. The reason is If we getting the new data set for replacing the exist data, that exist data set controlled with react.memo by the index. So that same indexed item is not re-render for viewing in the flatlist

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, my problem was passing arrow functions as props, I managed to fix this by replacing all my `fnProp={() => {}}` for `fnProp={someFunc}`

Another solution is to use `shouldComponentUpdate`. Being "YourWrappedItem" the item you are using as renderItem prop in FlatList, you could use a wrapper component like this:

```js
class ItemToRender extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <YourWrappedItem {...someProps}>
                Example
            </YourWrappedItem>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was Having same issue my data was being rendered more than once like if page chunk is 4 then i would have 16 results
My Code was:

```
renderItem = ({element}) => {
return (
  <View>
    {state &&
      state.data.map(element => (
        <View style={styles.mycard}>
          <View style={styles.cardView}>
            <Text>Name:{element.user.name}</Text>
            <Text>Designation:{element.designation}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
  </View>
);
```

};

I realised and  then i removed the data.map in my code and changed it to

```
renderItem = ({element}) => {
return (
  <View>
    {state && (
        <View style={styles.mycard}>
          <View style={styles.cardView}>
            <Text>Name:{element.user.name}</Text>
            <Text>Designation:{element.designation}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
  </View>
);
```

};

and that worked out for me!! Hope it helps someone who has same issue.
This is My first Overflow answer Sorry for Bad English And thanks for reading.

Comment: Hi Ameya Bhagat, this fundamentally changes what you are doing. Checking for a `state` and calling array.prototype.map on `state.data` is naturally going to render the length of `state.data` as The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Comment: hi Daniel Yes you are right, I realized it late and it might help someone like me facing same problem so I posted it, Thank you :)